# Drupal htaccess - ignore subdirectory

Tags: drupal, .htaccess

I have a drupal installation in my document root, and a different application stored in one of the subdirectories.

The application in the subdirectory seems to work fine until such time as I enable htpasswd for that subdirectory. Once I enable the htpasswd protection, then reloading the url brings up the standard Drupal error message:

```
Page not found
The requested page could not be found.
```

Is there a way for me to prevent this happening, or perhaps telling drupal's htaccess file to completely ignore this subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this, I found the answer at http://www.chipkin.com/articles/how-to-use-htaccess-on-subfolders-with-drupal